# accessing the fetched data in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, fetch-api

I've written some code that fetches json data from a url and inside of it, I push it's data into an array. Then I try to console.log the array, and I'm able to extend the brackets to see the json data inside but I'm not able to actually access the data. How could I do this? Here is my code,

```
let playerList = [];
fetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    playerList.push(data)
  });

console.log(playerList);
```

[Here is what it looks like on the developer console as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hc1qR.png)

Comment: You can see the reason [here](https://jsfiddle.net/40Lhb753/).

Comment: how could I fix this?

Comment: Read the the duplicate in the link and [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)